# How many rules does Magic have?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

More specifically, how many subrules exist in the September 25, 2014 revision of the Comprehensive Rules, located [here](http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/MagicCompRules_20140926.pdf)?

> 1 Game Concepts

Not a rule. This is a header.

> 100 General

Also not a rule. This is a subheader.

Just to clarify, CR 100.1 and CR 100.1a are two different subrules. Please explain how you arrived at your number. If your solution can be generalized to cover more than one revision, please note that.

Comment: This is a localized question, and is guaranteed to change with every revision. Why are you asking this?

Comment: @murgatroid99 It will not change with every revision, because I asked about a specific revision.

Comment: I know you asked for a specific revision, as my answer demonstrates. But what is the use of having the number of subrules in an old revision of the Comp Rules?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/20190/discussion-between-murgatroid99-and-rainbolt).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are **2008 subrules** in the September 26, 2014 revision of the Comprehensive Rules. I found this by running the following command on Linux:

```
curl --silent http://media.wizards.com/2014/downloads/MagicCompRules_20140926.txt | \
  grep -c '^\s*[0-9]\{3\}\.[0-9]\+[a-z]*'
```

This downloads the text version of the Comprehensive Rules and then finds every line that starts with 3 digits, a period, more digits, and possibly a letter (which is the pattern that represents a subrule).

The number of subrules in any other revision can be found by running the same command and replacing the URL with the URL of that revision's TXT rules page.

Comment: This number seems very small. I was bored and counted 376 just in section 1, and 702 looks like it has over 300 too.

Comment: That's a good point. I had a minor bug.

Comment: The rules with zeroes in them aren't very interesting anyway, don't worry.

Comment: New EDH variant: 00Commander, License to Mise.  Rules with 0s in them do not apply.

Comment: That number seems much more reasonable :)